# Magento Web Service - Custom API

Tags: api, web-services

Has anyone created a custom API or Web Services that will communicate directly with the Magento database?  The minimum requirements would need to support creation of new configurable products and order retrieval out of Magento?

The Magento API is extremely slow and we're looking for other alternatives.

Alex

Comment: What will the use case for this be? Thinking outside of the box, perhaps you can reverse the process, and have Magento query the other system instead. This way, you can create your products and export your orders from within Magento, without using its external API.

Comment: You can use some plugins like bulk product import...we had used one and works well

Comment: What I'm looking to resolve is going straight to the Magento db and avoiding the Slow API.  Creating Matrix items just takes forever and at times slows down.  I'm not looking to use spread sheets, and would like a New Magento API or Module that bypasses the API and offers a new Faster API interface.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right, your problem is the following:
The create of products is to slow via the magento default api endpoints?

In this case I think https://github.com/danslo/ApiImport is a good alternate with proper speed.

Answer (score 0):

Check out magmi code https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git, has a great performance creating products in bulk.